# Como comparar duas List e excluir os campos repetidos?

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Como comparar a `lista1` e a `lista2`, excluindo os itens repetidos em uma delas?

Comment: Coloque o exemplo da `lista1` e `lista2`?

Comment: Eu reverti a edição porque foi dada uma resposta presumindo o que estava na original, na forma editada a resposta aceita (e depois as demais que assumiram o mesmo) está inválida. Eu acho que até que a pergunta não estava clara para ser respondida mesmo, mas como foi respondida e até aceita, sei lá porque, já que não resolve o problema real, então é melhor deixar a pergunta como estava e uma nova pergunta deve ser feita com o problema real. Só tomar o cuidado de fazer uma pergunta completa e clara. Mesmo a edição não tem tudo o que precisaria para responder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assumindo que `T` é o tipo das suas listas:

```
foreach(T t in lista1) 
{
    if(lista2.Contains(t))
        lista2.Remove(t);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Segundo a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx), não é necessário verificar se o item existe antes de remover. Você pode remover direto. Não dará erro algum.
Você pode fazer assim:

```
foreach(T t in lista1) 
{
    lista2.Remove(t);
}
```

Caso `t` não exista em `lista2` não acontecerá nada.

Comment: massa, vou testar

Comment: Legal! Não sei se você viu o edit do post.. Mais simples :-)

Comment: Amigo, agora que vi seus detalhes sobre as listas. Ambos os tipos herdam de uma classe em comum? Classe Produto, por exemplo? Se sim, você deve comparar através do método `Equals()`. Se forem iguais, aí sim você remove!

Comment: isso mesmo, as listas contem objetos diferentes, embora os ambos tenham os mesmos atributos

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo se são objetos diferentes isso não vai funcionar. Na verdade acho que a pergunta não está clara quanto a isso e provavelmente todas as respostas estariam erradas com essa nova informação. Precisaria de mais detalhes para dar uma resposta que realmente solucione o problema, mas provavelmente em outra pergunta, sta já está comprometida. Se me disser que que esta ou outra resposta funcionou, o que você afirma aqui não é verdade.

Comment: @bigown eu respondi quando a pergunta dele consistia apenas na primeira linha. Não tinha o resto do corpo. Comentei nessa mesma resposta o que ele poderia fazer para dar certo.

Comment: @igorventurelli Eu acho que vou reverter a edição para deixar a pergunta de acordo com as respostas, porque na forma atual nenhuma resposta é válida, aí ele pode fazer outra pergunta para resolver o problema real.

Comment: obrigado pessoal. vou deixar essa pergunta aqui e vou criar outra explicando melhor a questão da minha dúvida.

Comment: Possuo a mesma situação mas o @Maniero removeu minha pergunta, minha lista não é retirado os itens duplicados dessa forma que passou e são do mesmo tipo, existe outra forma ?

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito, @StandAlone , mas acho que vc pode usar uma implementação de Set, ao invés de lista.

Answer (score 6):

Se o que você quer são os elementos da lista 2 que não existem na lista 1 recorra a método [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var notInList1 = lista2.Except(lista1).ToList();
```

Exemplo:

```
lista 1 => 1, 2, 3, 4
lista 2 => 1, 3, 4, 5, 6

notInList1 => 5, 6
```

Answer (score 5):

Se eu entendi bem, com LINQ é a forma mais simples:

```
lista2 = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Distinct.cs).